# Wordpress nginx redirect loop

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, nginx

So, yesterday I had a question how to install the wordpress in the "/root" directory. I wasn't very successful in that one and I forgo'ed on that one.

So, right now the wordpress is located under "**/var/www/wordpress**" (so it's under separate folder) folder (I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, if it matters).

And my problem is that right after I had configured everything (everything was working like a charm there) I was redirected to the admin panel page. Everything was working fine up until the moment when I tried to visit the blog.

The URL address for my blog is: "blog.mysite.com". That is why I use NGINX, because I have two different applications (and environments) on one server and I need to distinguish between them.

So, the fact is: blog.mysite.com/wp-admin (/wp-login.php) is working totally OK, but when I visit the front page: **blog.mysite.com**, it keeps telling me that there is an endless redirect loop (301 redirect according to nginx access log file).

In admin panel I have both "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site address (URL)" set to: "http://blog.mysite.com". Modifying either of them to something else, like: "http://blog.mysite.com/wordpress" is not helping at all!

".htaccess" file is empty, but I'm using default permalinks, so should not be a problem (However, I'm not sure).

Both nginx and apache2 root directives are pointing to "/var/www/wordpress". 
Static files (css,js) are working, if it matters.

How can I fix this problem ? Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: @ark Hi. Yes. It turned out that our WP installation was faulty, so it wasn't the nginx issue after all :( 
If you have something similar, try re-installing or installing a clean blog next to your existing one and see if that works first before you start touching the nginx.

Comment: same problem by other solution : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/220896/127528

Answer (score 16):

Not the prettiest fix, but removing the redirect filter in your theme `functions.php` file worked for me.

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

From the link provided in [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19995353/1218980):
[Wordpress did infinite 301 redirect loop](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/firefox-has-detected-that-the-server-is-redirecting-the-request-for-this-address)

Comment: holy crap.  40 hours later, i finally have an answer and it's one freakin' line.

Comment: Welcome to wordpress tinkering!

Comment: That's genius. Spent half day trying to figure out through nginx logs.

Comment: Same here wasted whole day and this was it just one line. oh man i hate wordpress when this happen

Answer (score 9):

Finally, found a solution:

http://www.violato.net/blog/php/88-wordpress-did-infinite-301-redirect-loop

Hope this will help others that have the same problem as I did.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: This is not loading anymore. If you have the solution on your end, can you please edit your answer and add them directly? Thanks

Comment: The link outline's Emile's response included here. Poor formatting but in case its redacted, add the following to your theme's functions.php file:

    remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem using Nginx as a reverse proxy for Apache.

After a few hours I found out it was caused by the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` being set to `index.php` by Nginx instead of the actual url and Wordpress was trying to remove `index.php` by redirecting to the url without `index.php` in `wp-includes/canonical.php`.

The solution for me is using something like this,

```
proxy_pass http://111.111.111.111:8080$request_uri;
```

So adding the `$request_uri` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a lot of problems when switching from Apache to Nginx in the past, all solved when I purged Apache, which somehow was interfering with Nginx and caused problems to every server. Here is my wordpress configuration for Nginx, according to both Nginx and Wordpress guides for each other:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blog.mysite.com;

    root /var/www/wordpress;
    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php;

      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # CHANGE THE LINE ABOVE IF NEEDED
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I didn't even have to change anything in the admin panel when switching servers, it just worked fine.

Comment: Everything I have on my VPS: PHP (php5, php5-mysql, libs), Apache2 - is a fresh install. 

They were pre-installed on the VPS, but I purged both of them and made a fresh install. 

So, I clearly don't understand what is going on there and why this redirect occurs in the first place (Considering the fact that the admin panel is working flawlessly)

But, many thanks!

BTW, I don't use "fastcgi" directive, I just proxy pass it to Apache:
proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8081 (I have defined the port by myself)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the redirect loop only affected wp-admin pages, so I added at the start of the line

```
if (is_admin) remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

and still works, plus the redirect canonical keeps doing its job on the front end!

I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue because I was using nginx to forward the request, but nginx wasn't preserving the HOST header.

Once I added these values under my `location` block things started working as expected.

```
    # Set proxy headers for the passthrough
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # Let the Set-Cookie header through.
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for nginx with wordpress docker
The key point is to add "host" and "proto" to proxy

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @apache;
}

location @apache {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://wordpress:80;
}
```

references:
https://azdigi.com/blog/en/website-tutorials/wordpress-en/how-to-install-wordpress-with-docker-compose-nginx-apache-and-ssl-2/