# nginx & wordpress not working correctly (subfolder)

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I've got a website with wordpress in a subfolder (/tips) and I just can't get it  working properly on nginx. In Chrome it more or less works but on Edge it just doesn't work at all.

It's on Ubuntu 16.04 with php5.

I tried to get it working with the documentation on wordpress.org (location = /tips) but it would just 404. Hence, I had to use a rewrite as you'll see below.

Here's the existing nginx config:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name  www.domain.co.uk;

add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
root /var/www/domain.co.uk;
index index.php;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www_domain_co_uk.key;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS +RC4 RC4";
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

rewrite ^/tips/(.*) /tips/index.php?$args;

if (!-f $request_filename) {
    set $rule_3 1$rule_3;
}
if (!-d $request_filename) {
    set $rule_3 2$rule_3;
}
if ($uri !~ ".*.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)") {
    set $rule_3 3$rule_3;
}
if ($rule_3 = "321") {
    rewrite ^/([^?]*) /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
}

location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
    access_log        off;
    log_not_found     off;
    expires           30d;
}
```

}

Comment: I should have said : 

Chrome - loads pages fine but /wp-admin reports "too many redirects".
Edge - doesn't load the images or page properly at all, has a box in the corner labelled 'Skip to content'

Comment: Chrome has a disgustingly sticky cache these days, I'd be surprised if it wasn't actually broken in Chrome. Use icognito mode, check with Firefox as well

Comment: And "too many redirects" with apache means you've got an infinite redirect setup, usually from a rewriterule but I'm no good with nginx so don't really understand the syntax

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a 404 for every call that matches an existing file?

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
}
```

Comment: If I remove the crappy redirect I put in and put the above in then the homepage works fine but permalinks 404.

Comment: No. That means return a 404 when nothing matches.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like every page that goes to /tips gets redirected back to /tips...

that really does look like an infinite redirect

```
rewrite ^/tips/(.*) /tips/index.php?$args;
```

a quick google suggests something like that but again I'm not 100% sure on what you're trying to achieve

```
location /tips/ {
    try_files $uri /index.php$args =404;
}
```

Comment: similar sort of question here but they don't have WP in a subfolder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19980354/884842

Comment: With that it works fine for the homepage but the permalinks 404

Comment: maybe you don't need the /tips/ part inside the /tips location block - updated the answer, I probably shouldn't be helping though, I'm straining to remember from when I last used nginx

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the problem was - it was a conflict with the core site rewrite (for opencart). Fixed with the following:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @opencart;
}

location @opencart {
    rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
}

location /tips/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /tips/index.php?$args;
}
```